# Flutter Integration testing failing when moving between tests

Tags: flutter, flutter-integration-test

Currently in my project I am adding multiple integration tests separated in different files. When trying to run all tests running using `flutter test integration test`, it gives me this error when moving between tests

`Error waiting for a debug connection: The log reader stopped unexpectedly, or never started.`
`TestDeviceException(Unable to start the app on the device.)`

This error never occurs when running it on an iOS or Android emulator, but as this is a desktop application, I need to get the tests building on Linux which is where the error is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help you:

sdk version . choose win 11 sdk(10.0.22000.0) in visual studio installer
windows 11 need choose win 11 sdk(10.0.22000.0)

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/93635#issuecomment-969053206

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to get my desktop integration tests to work with a single command but if I write each test out as its own command, it works:

```
flutter test integration_test/features/fast_booking/fast_booking_test.dart --dart-define=FLAVOR=staging --dart-define=FLUTTER_TEST=true;flutter test integration_test/features/appointments/book_appointment_test.dart --dart-define=FLAVOR=staging --dart-define=FLUTTER_TEST=true
```

It's not the prettiest solution and I'm hoping the Flutter team releases an official solution.

### Related Issues

Most of these are Windows specific but they don't solve the problem on MacOS.

- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/72985
- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/111076
- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/93635
- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/98890
- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/79723